# to stalk the block

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I cannot find the definition of the verb phrase "to stalk the block". Can someone explain this?

The context is:

> After yuppies and dinkies, a new creature from adland **stalks the block.**
> <sub>Source: [The Economist > Social trends >
>   High rollers > *Marketing dreams from New York to London*](http://www.economist.com/node/656638)</sub>

Comment: It means "can be seen out and about", or more literally "can be seen walking up and down the block". Although blocks are synonymous with the USA (and may be used elsewhere, I don't know) the phrase is likely to be well understood anywhere US TV has an influence I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It's an unusual way of saying "to be around."

"To stalk" is used, figuratively, in this context to mean "to be in an area in search of prey." "The block" is slang for "a neighborhood" [from a city block.]

So, what they're saying is "A new creature from adland is in the neighborhood."

More literally, they mean "After yuppies and dinkies, there is a new category of person being discussed in marketing departments."